# How can I install this gem?

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, installation

I have tried to install this gem from github with the command git but the console doesn't recognize it as a command.
Any other alternative ways to install it? link: https://github.com/xofred/deviantart-gallery-downloader Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Git is not the tool to install gems. You install a gem with `gem install`. The instructions to do so are usually provided on a gem's github readme.

Comment: this gem is not in the ruby database and it can't be installed with that command and the instructions aren't in the readme.

Comment: If that is the case then you need to follow the solution that Rick Majpruz provided. This also means that this isn't a gem. Instead it is just a ruby project.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to include `clone` with your `git` command:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/xofred/deviantart-gallery-downloader.git
```

This will clone a copy of the code on the GitHub repo. Then follow the instructions in the `README.md` file to complete the install and start using.

... or follow Daniel Owsley's answer and just use `gem install` if you're not interested in getting the repo source.

Comment: I tried it but neither is recognized as command by the console.

Comment: Odd. Because that command is recognized for me. What OS are you using? If it is Linux or MacOS then issue `which git` at the console ... there's something equivalent on Windows. Maybe you don't have git installed? If not then search on installing git for your specific OS.